# HTML5 Pattern Attribute: Exclude Keywords

Tags: regex, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to write an HTML5 pattern to prevent users from entering free email accounts.  So far I have this...

```
<input name="email"
placeholder="Work Email"
required
type="email"
title="Enter a valid work email address (No free email services)"
pattern="^((?!hotmail)(?!gmail)(?!ymail)(?!googlemail)(?!live)(?!gmx)(?!yahoo)(?!outlook)(?!msn)(?!icloud)(?!facebook)(?!aol)(?!zoho)(?!mail)(?!yandex)(?!hushmail)(?!lycox)(?!lycosmail)(?!inbox)(?!myway)(?!aim)(?!fastmail)(?!goowy)(?!juno)(?!shortmail)(?!atmail)(?!protonmail).)*$"/>
```

It is close, but is missing two key rules...

- Should only look at what comes between the '@' and the '.'
- Should be case insensitive.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

**UPDATE**
To avoid unhelpful comments about if I should be doing this, consider other use cases where an input field should not contain a list of known keywords. A similar use case could be swear words or an ID prefix where multiple prefixes exist, but you want to avoid just one type being entered...  ID should never contain IXT and user enters... WIN-09880, IXT-2342, NTS-23422.

Comment: Yes, read more about lookaheads and make tests to well understand what they are and how they work. Note that you can use an alternation inside them. Search about inline modifiers. Describe all the beginning until the "@".

Comment: As an aside, preventing users to enter a free email address is a very strange idea.

Comment: *This* part of the address does not need to be case sensitive, email domains are not case sensitive and if input case is important you can do a string to lower case conversion once the data is received from the form.

Comment: What if they work at Facebook or work at Microsoft? Or work at Yahoo? You are denying them use of their work email when this is specifically what you're requesting.

Comment: @Martin I'm using the HTML5 pattern attribute to prevent a user from entering free email accounts into a form field.  So converting to lowercase would need to happen before the user submits the form to use HTML5 validation.  I suppose I could apply it on blur.

Comment: @Martin  I'm assuming internal employees do not use the same domain name extension as the free extensions.   I should probably look more into that, unless someone else here knows for sure.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte  It's definitely a strange ask, but I work for a SaaS provider and we want to clean up the flood of leads we are receiving by asking specifically for work email addresses.

Comment: Just  FYI: One can't use inline modifiers in an HTML5 pattern attribute as JS regex does not support them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really bad idea, but in the spirit of answering your question, here is my answer.

You can use:

```
pattern="^.+@((?!hotmail)(?!gmail)(?!ymail)(?!googlemail)(?!live)(?!gmx)(?!yahoo)(?!outlook)(?!msn)(?!icloud)(?!facebook)(?!aol)(?!zoho)(?!mail)(?!yandex)(?!hushmail)(?!lycox)(?!lycosmail)(?!inbox)(?!myway)(?!aim)(?!fastmail)(?!goowy)(?!juno)(?!shortmail)(?!atmail)(?!protonmail).)+\..+$"
```

to only look between the '@' and the '.'. HTML5 doesn't support the i flag for case-insensitivity, so you will either need to use JavaScript or hardcode case-insensitivity into the pattern.

Comment: You can do a bit shorter: `^.+@(?:(?!(g|hot|y|google|hush|fast|at|short|at|proton)?mail)(?!live)(?!gmx)(?!yahoo)(?!outlook)(?!msn)(?!icloud)(?!facebook)(?!aol)(?!zoho)(?!yandex)(?!lycox)(?!inbox)(?!myway)(?!aim)(?!goowy)(?!juno).)+\..+$`

Answer (score 0):

You *can't*:

- I've found a non-exhaustive list of free email providers which contains **2840** entries.
- You'll block users that works at Microsoft, Google, Facebook, Yahoo, ProtonMail, Free, Orange, Sfr and a lot others.
- What will you do with users that have theirs domains name?

Comment: While this isn't a technical answer to the question asked, I fully agree (as stated in comments above) with the bullet point reasonings for the conclusion reached. So annoyingly I want to -1 for not being a code solution answer but +1 for the logical reasoning..... +1 wins, just....

Comment: @Martin I'm not sure that a *good* answer must be a code answer. The question is "*Any ideas on how to get this working?*" and I think that my answer fit. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I would think  *good* answer would note the issues (as you have) but provide the regex that would enable the issue to be resolved. The root issue is detecting substrings in a input, rather than *Why* the poster wants to do this `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a corrected (and shortened) version of your regex that targets only the domain portion of the address:

`^(?!.*@(?:hotmail|gmail|ymail|googlemail|live|gmx|yahoo|outlook|msn|icloud|facebook|aol|zoho|mail|yandex|hushmail|lycox|lycosmail|inbox|myway|aim|fastmail|goowy|juno|shortmail|atmail|protonmail)\.\w+$).*$`

You can shorten it further if you need to:

`^(?!.*@(?:live|gmx|yahoo|outlook|msn|icloud|facebook|aol|zoho|yandex|lycox|inbox|myway|aim|goowy|juno|(?:hot|[gy]|google|short|at|proton|hush|lycos|fast)?mail)\.\w+$).*$`

You can't make it case insensitive because the JavaScript regex flavor, very annoyingly, doesn't support inline modifiers.  But do you have to use a regex for this?  I would prefer a code solution using an updatable list of banned domains.